# SQLAlchemy Insert data from Select, between two DBs

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The goals are:

1. to be able to bind to two separate PostgreSQL databases using SQLAlchemy
2. select from one table of a database and insert into the other database.

The table schema is the same for both databases.

This is a flask application, and I have no control over the external database. I can only read from it and as mentioned above, I want to insert the data into the internal database.

This is what I came up with so far.

#### settings

```
db_internal = 'postgresql://internal:password@postgres_1:5432/internal'
db_external = 'postgresql://external:password@postgres_2:5432/external'

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = db_internal
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
    'internal': db_internal,
    'external': db_external
}
```

#### table

```
class TemplateTable(object):
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, unique=True, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    u_no = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    u_age = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
    u_gender = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
```

#### model for external DB

(the one that I have no control over, but only select)

```
class ExternalView(TemplateTable, db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'external'
    __tablename__ = 'external_table'

    @classmethod
    def selection(cls, cols, start, end):
        q = db.select(cols).where(
            and_(
                ExternalView.id > int(start),
                ExternalView.id <= int(end)
            )
        )

        return q
```

#### model for internal DB

(the one that I want to insert data into)

```
class InternalTable(TemplateTable, db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'internal'
    __tablename__ = 'internal_table'

    @classmethod
    def insert_from_select(cls, start, end, data):

        cols = [ExternalView.id, ExternalView.u_no, ExternalView.u_age, ExternalView.u_gender]
        sel = ExternalView.selection(cols, start, end)

        q = InternalTable.__table__.insert().from_select(['id', 'u_no', 'u_age', 'u_gender'], sel)

        db.session.execute(q, data)
        db.session.commit()

        return True
```

With this setup, there is absolutely no problem when it comes to achieving goal no.1.

However, for goal no.2, when calling `insert_from_select`, I get the following error:

```
postgres_1    | ERROR:  relation "external_table" does not exist at character 178                                                                                                                                            
postgres_1    | STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO internal_table (id, u_no, u_age, u_gender) SELECT external_table.id, external_table.u_no, external_table.u_age, external_table.u_gender               
postgres_1    |         FROM external_table                                                                                                                                                                                  
postgres_1    |         WHERE external_table.id > 0 AND external_table.id <= 6
```

How can I achieve goal no.2?

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot do that, unless you present *external_table* as a [foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) or such. In essence in your current attempt you're trying to query over 2 connections simultaneously. Binds support routing queries to the correct connectable, but queries are sent to a single connection at a time. It'd seem to pick the bind for `InternalTable` in your case.

Comment: @IljaEverilä that makes sense. Thank you. Any idea how to declare a foreign table in SQLAlchemy with ORM? or should I go with custom DDL?

Comment: I don't think it's directly feasible using Declarative. Some combination of custom DDL and reflection is probably required.